# About asp.net core angular 2 starter application structure

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any resource to learn asp.net core angular 2 starter application structure, file format and what the responsibilities of each file?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on an ASP.Net Core and Angular Application for past 2 or 3 months. There is a new template available now and it is much better than the old template. I also ran into a lot of issues in the old version of template provided by Visual Studio. The new template is available in ASP.Net Core 2.1 by default, else you need to follow instructions in below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

If you are looking for a working example with EF Core 2, Angular Material and ASP.Net Core Web API please refer below link

http://hive.rinoy.in/building-a-web-app-using-asp-net-core-2-and-angular5-frameworks/